# Error while firing up wubi installer on Windows XP

Tags: wubi

i've tried to run the Wubi Installer on Windows XP, but it throws a really strange
exception. It looks like this:

Header:
'Windows - No drive'

Content: 
'Exception Processing Message c0000013 Paramters 75b0bf9c 4 75b0bf9c 75b0bf9c'

It doesn´t matter which button I press cause nothing happens.
The only way to stop that annoying window is to kill the pyrun.exe process.
I've also checked for an error log, like the one i found on the Windows 7 Netbook,
but nothing.

Any help would be very nice.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/365881). It has workarounds, like removing MMC readers, any peripheral devices not required etc. Or you can also just click cancel multiple times to get past the issue.

Comment: Now the installer has worked perfect (except that window ;) ) Thanks for that answer